# Python convert multipart/form-data to json

Tags: python, json, multipartform-data

I'm currently working with an API that sends .json files in a multipart/form-data body as a response.

Is there a way to split the received multipart/form-data into separate files with a python script?

below an example of the response I'm receiving:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2023-04-28T18:54:32.204432Z",
    "user_agent": {
        "original": "Jersey/2.31 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_121)"
    },
    "host": {
        "ip": "172.20.10.2"
    },
    "message": "--Boundary_66_15756658_1682708071578\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"123.json\"; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n{\"firmware\":{\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"ENABLED\":false,\"SEQUENCE\":1,\"METHOD\":417}\n\r\n--Boundary_66_15756658_1682708071578\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"123.json\"; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n{\"firmware\":{\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"ENABLED\":false,\"SEQUENCE\":1,\"METHOD\":417}",
    "http": {
        "request": {
            "body": {
                "bytes": "1195069"
            },
            "mime_type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=Boundary_66_15756658_1682708071578"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "version": "HTTP/1.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using `requests` library , you can convert response to json like this for expamle:

make your request :

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

and convert response to json:

```
json_response = json.loads(response.text)
```

In general, by using the ‍‍‍`json()` like `response.json()`, you can receive the response as a json.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not using requests but Logstash which outputs the data to a file. Anyway requests could read from a file?

Comment: Yes, requests can read data from a file. When you pass a file object to requests, it will read the data from the file and send it in the request.






url = "https://example.com/"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
}

with open("file.txt", "rb") as file:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=file)